# I added Firebase Authentication and now my AndroidManifest is broken

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am building an app to find cigarettes dispensers in my area, but as I wanted to implement the Firebase and Google Sign In SDK, my whole Android Manifest and Strings.xml file broke down.
This is my Manifest-file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.turksat46.cigarettesfinder"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.2.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the "MyLocation" functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the "MyLocation" functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <queries>

        <!-- Needs to be explicitly declared on Android R+ -->
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
        <!-- For browser content -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent> <!-- End of browser content -->
        <!-- For CustomTabsService -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CigarettesFinder" >

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.turksat46.cigarettesfinder.setMarkerActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_set_marker" />
        <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="cannot include that" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.turksat46.cigarettesfinder.MapsActivity3"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps3" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.turksat46.cigarettesfinder.MapsActivity2"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps2" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.turksat46.cigarettesfinder.MapsActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.turksat46.cigarettesfinder.SettingsActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
        <activity android:name="com.turksat46.cigarettesfinder.MenuPage" />
        <!-- Needs to be explicitly declared on P+ -->
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="firebase.auth"
                    android:path="/"
                    android:scheme="genericidp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="firebase.auth"
                    android:path="/"
                    android:scheme="recaptcha" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.api.fallback.service.FirebaseAuthFallbackService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.service.START" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--
            Service handling Google Sign-In user revocation. For apps that do not integrate with
            Google Sign-In, this service will never be started.
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION"
            android:visibleToInstantApps="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.turksat46.cigarettesfinder.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" /> <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.turksat46.cigarettesfinder.mobileadsinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="com.turksat46.cigarettesfinder.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>

        <service
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.SystemAlarmService"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="@bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="@bool/enable_system_job_service_default"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="@bool/enable_system_foreground_service_default"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable$BroadcastReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxy$BatteryChargingProxy"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxy$BatteryNotLowProxy"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxy$StorageNotLowProxy"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_STORAGE_OK" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxy$NetworkStateProxy"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxyUpdateReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="@bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.UpdateProxies" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.diagnostics.DiagnosticsReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.DUMP" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.work.diagnostics.REQUEST_DIAGNOSTICS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="androidx.room.MultiInstanceInvalidationService"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What do I need to do, to fix this?
I am really confused and I don't wanna delete this project!

Comment: What are your errors ?

Comment: Try doing 'invalidate cache and restart' or 'invalidate caches' under File menu

Comment: It says "Android resource linking failed"

Comment: And I did try to invalidate cache, but it didn't help

Comment: The manifest that you posted seems to be the one generated by the compiler. Or am I wrong?

Comment: No, you are right. But I am really confused af right now XD

Comment: I have over 120 errors but on top of all these errors is "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)"

Comment: Show us how you setup Firebase auth? If you got it wrong then the library will generate broken xml

Comment: post the log of errors you have please

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it

Comment: The error was, that it found somehow a duplicate string ressource and I just deleted it. It was uninportant